# OMNeT emit complex signals

Tags: omnet++

I'm having trouble emitting some signals from my modules in OMNeT. In particular, one of my module has an array of signals to emit, something like:

```
simsignal_t* signalInputInterarrivalTime;
...
signalInputInterarrivalTime = new simsignal_t[N];
```

and then I `registerSignal` each element in the array with a different name.
This way works, however in my .ned file I have to use as many `@statistic` rows as the maximum size of the array. This is of course not the best way, being nor parametric neither readable. Is it possible to declare a vector of signals to emit, something that fits better my case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to [dynamically create statistics](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:statistic-recording-dynamic-signals) in `OMNeT++`.
Add these lines to your `NED` file:

```
@signal[interarrivalTime*](type=simtime_t); // note an asterisk and the type of emitted values
@statisticTemplate[interarrivalTimeTemplate](record=vector);
```

Then declare in your `C++` class:

```
simsignal_t interarrivalTimeSignals[10];
```

and create multiple instances of statistics:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    char signalName[32];
    sprintf(signalName, "interarrivalTime%d", i);
    simsignal_t signal = registerSignal(signalName);
    cProperty *statisticTemplate = getProperties()->get("statisticTemplate", "interarrivalTimeTemplate");
    getEnvir()->addResultRecorders(this, signal, signalName,  statisticTemplate);
    interarrivalTimeSignals[i] = signal;
}
```

An example of using it:

```
simtime_t delay = simTime() - msg->getSendingTime();
emit(interarrivalTimeSignals[3], delay);
```

Note that the type of emitting value has to match the type declared in `NED`.